# Cases of nationalists wanting to cede sovereignty to supranational organisations

Tags: european-union, nationalism, globalization

In the UK there are two explicitly nationalist political parties, Plaid Cymru and the SNP, that curiously advocate handing sovereignty to the EU.

Are there nationalist parties anywhere else in the world that advocate for something similar?

Comment: These are probably better described as sub-nationalist parties. And they don't advocate handing sovereignty to the EU, they advocate maintaining the status-quo of being in the EU.

Comment: @jontia they seek independence for countries that are not members of the EU and even if that was the case being a member of the EU means ceding sovereignty over significant areas of governance.

Comment: My point was that those areas of governance are already controlled by the EU, so they are not advocating "handing" over anything they currently control. By any measure, an independent Scotland or Wales within the EU would have more control over their own territory then they do now.

Comment: The question is flawed. Plaid and the SNP do not consider joining the EU to be ceding sovereignty, they believe that it enhances it. As part of a larger group, with power such a veto, they have more control over their own destiny than they do alone.

Comment: @user whether they consider it to be or not is irrelevant. By any definition they are ceding sovereignty.

Comment: @user1450877 Which definition? Seems more like they are pooling it.

Answer (score 6):

The premise of this question is flawed as one user put it;

> Plaid and the SNP do not consider joining the EU to be ceding sovereignty, they believe that it enhances it. As part of a larger group, with power such a veto, they have more control over their own destiny than they do alone.

Even accepting the broad sweep of the Questioners' position then yes, there are a number of similar examples available.

The most obvious direct comparison is [Catalonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_independence_movement), the El Periodico poll table includes one poll that specifically asked for support for independence if it meant exclusion from the EU, it showed support dropping by 10%.

Other similar groups exist in [Kosovo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosovo#Government), a number of the sub-parties within the ruling Alliance for the Future party are described as nationalist, and Kosovo wants to be an EU member.

Looking further afield, the logic in the question would apply to the [Six Californias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Californias) proposal in the US. In this case the "nationalist" groups no longer want to be controlled by the state of California, but would be handing sovereignty to the US.

Comment: List of [active separatist movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_active_separatist_movements).

Answer (score 2):

The question is flawed. Plaid and the SNP do not consider joining the EU to be ceding sovereignty, they believe that it enhances it. As part of a larger group, with power such a veto, they have more control over their own destiny than they do alone.

Comment: How is the supremacy of EU law and the EU courts over National law and courts not ceding sovereignty. It's fiction to think otherwise.

Comment: Well A) is it really ceded if the decision to leave can be taken unilaterally, and B) it's felt that on balance the overall effect is a net gain.

Comment: @user1450877 No EU law comes into effect without approval of Parliament, Commission and *Council*, the latter being composed of representatives of all currently 28 sovereign national governments. Consensus is an important principle in the council and thus compromises are typically found that most states agree on. In addition, each country appoints a commissioner and elects members of the EU parliament so I thoroughly fail to follow your fiction argument.